# Connecting 6.5kw sauna heater to 20 amp plug

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, cord-and-plug, electric-heat

I have a sauna in a trailer and I want to buy 6.5kw 220V single phase heater and connect it to electricity in the house I rent(US). I have access to 6-20R outlet and I understand that it supposed to give me 20 amp and my heater requires 30 amp. I plan to move to my own house one day and connect it properly, but for now would this plan work if I would turn on the heater only to half of it's capacity and put 20 amp breaker before the outlet?

- If no, would this plan work with 4.5kw heater?
- Do I understand correctly that I need https://www.wireandcableyourway.com/10-3-sjoow-portable-cord-300v-ul-csa as wire(cord to be precise) since I'll need 30 amp down the road.
- Would I break any regulations with such plan?
- Is this plan dangerous?
- What can be done to improve this plan?
- Am I out of my mind doing it myself and not talking to licensed electrician or I have a good enough plan to be executed by amateur?

Comment: is it in California?

Comment: your plan to only operate it at half power doesn't seem safe,   modify it so that it's incapable of exceeding 4800W

Comment: The maximum load on a 240v circuit is 3840w any higher would not be code compliant to the NEC.

Comment: @aaaaasaysreinstateMonica yes, California

Answer (score 0):

4800w would not meet code requirements on a 20 a 240v circuit.
The maximum load on a 20a 240v circuit would be 3840w by code.
Here is the calculation;
240v x 20a = 4800w x  .8 = 3840w  this is the maximum
The .8 is the same as x 125% of the load for the safety factor required by code.
The cable MFG rate different types of cables based on there type the same gauge of SO cord as premier wiring has a higher ampacity but we are still limited by the circuit itself.

Comment: Ok, it's not up to a code. But is this plan reasonable?

Comment: As a licensed electrician I can’t suggest that a overloaded circuit would be acceptable, if your sauna has several settings (some do)and the lowest setting meets the numbers, sure I would do it ,,but especially as a renter if you damaged the wiring and I have repaired wiring in a college town that cost the renter many times what it should’ve because code updates were required and even after legal the owner won.